5V to 12V inverting logic shifter
I have a 12V alarm siren that consumes about 270 mA when turned on. I'd like to turn it on/off based on the 5V logic output from the MCU. The MCU port is able to sink/source 10 mA @ 5V, but the logic needs to be inverted i.e. high level on the output from the MCU should not supply the siren while low level should turn it on.
I approached it as depicted on the circuit below. My question is if this is a correct approach or maybe should I do it better. The LOAD on the circuit represents siren, while L is the output from the MCU. Transistors that I use currently are consecutively MPSA92 and S9013 as only those I found in my inventory. Any better choice?


It is highly unlikely your MCU can drive 100mA, at least not without being damaged.

Fair point, there is a typo, and I corrected it. I meant 10 mA

You should probably reduce resistances a little, and add a diode to protect Q2 against a potentially inductive load:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Other than that, you're good to go. This will sink about 2mA from the MCU output, much more reasonable than the doesn't-sound-right 100mA you quoted.

Thank you so much for your input! I am going to check it right now. Yes, the 100 mA was a typo, and I meant 10 mA.

@noonespecial I don't know who downvoted your questrion, but I was actually pleasantly surprised by the very sane arrangement of your transistors. Whether you knew it or not, the PNP transistor high-side is the only way to obtain sufficient base current for the NPN. Good job!

Works like a dream :) Yeah, I did it accidentally when I tried to invert the logic. But now I know so thank you twice for your insights. Your help is invaluable!
